# Windows 10 hardware based activation

Tags: windows-7, windows-10

Recently our client asked to upgrade one of his employees hard drive to an SSD. In order to make this transition as smooth as possible, we decided to install windows 7 pro, activate it(because they had win 7 pro keys leftover) and then upgrade to windows 10 pro. Then just swap the old HDD to a fast new SSD.

Everything worked on my computer: I installed Win7, activated it, then upgraded to Win10 pro and it was still activated.

But when I swapped employees old hard drive to this new SSD, the OS lost it's activation and it wouldn't re-activate.

Most likely because employee was running windows 10 home before and it was tied to that hardware. Is there a way to remove the "*link*" between that specific hardware and Home version of Windows?

Comment: When you say, "Then just swap the old HDD to a fast new SSD," do you mean you cloned the HDD to the SSD? Your description is a little ambiguous. It's hard to tell if you cloned the old drive to the SSD or performed a clean install of Windows 10 Pro on the SSD.

Comment: Windows activation has never had anything to do with the storage device.  Your activation issue like has to do with the fact that it is technically no longer possible to use a Windows 7 key to activate Windows 10. It also has never been possible to activate Windows 10 Home with a Windows 7 Professional license key.

Comment: @Ramhound I get that it's not related to a HDD or SSD. And it is possible to upgrade windows 7 to windows 10, because I was able to do it on my test pc, (not through GWX obvsly) but by downloading windows 10 iso and just running an upgrade. And yes, I get that it's not possible to upgrade from win7pro to win10 Home and I don't want that. The problem is that when I swapped in the new ssd, windows couldn't activate, because the rest of the hardware was tied to Home version of version, and I am trying to find out, whether it is possible to active a pro version of windows on that hardware.

Comment: @wrecclesham I didn't clone it. I just clean installed windows 10 pro.

Comment: @sharksWithLasers - The Windows 10 free upgrade offer expired over 2 years ago.  Likewise, if you had any activation issues, it was due to the edition that was installed did not match the key.  It does not matter if a Windows 10 Home license was installed on the machine, that would not prevent you, from installing Windows 10 Professional on the same machine.

Comment: You cannot activate windows on one pc then transfer the hard drive to another pc and expect it to stay activated, just wont work.

Comment: @sharksWithLasers you've actually done everything right so far. Hang on. I'll post the answer for you.

Comment: @Moab But I did. I did the before mentioned procedure on one laptop, then transferred the new ssd onto my own laptop, to see if activation stays, and it stayed. But the activation did not stay when I transferred the ssd onto employees PC.

Comment: @sharksWithLasers sorry for the delay. I've posted an answer. Let me know how it goes!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are the three lines of troubleshooting you should try, in order to solve your activation problem:

**1. Activation Troubleshooter**

- this is the quickest and easiest possible solution and is the best place to start:

[image]

- Run the activation troubleshooter
- If this fails, move on to the next solution...

**2. Associate your old and new installations to the same Microsoft account**

1. Temporarily swap the new SSD with the old HDD, where your previously activated Windows 10 Pro installation still resides
2. Open the Activation settings page and click on "Add an account":

[image]

3. Sign in using a Microsoft account:

[image]

4. Swap the old HDD with your new SSD, and sign in using the same Microsoft account as in Step 3.

Windows may be able to reactivate with no problems at this point.

Failing that:

**3. Phone Microsoft Support**

- Phone Microsoft and explain the problem to them. They may be able to resolve this.